# Request e Response em JSTL, quando usar?

Tags: java

estou errado ao falar que `request` eu vou resgatar o que enviei para uma "action"? E `response`? Li em vários lugares sobre e não entendi muito bem, não ficou claro pra mim... Alguém consegue resumir esses dois parâmetros do `HttpServlet`?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Eu não sei em qual momento usar o response, o request eu uso pegando dados enviados por um formulário, por exemplo... e o response? Uso pra passar dados pra algum lugar? (resposta?)

Comment: `JSTL` entra em que lugar na sua dúvida?

Comment: @BrunoCésar, valeu a ajuda, mas na hora da prova eu consegui entender... puro desespero, mas foi. uuashuhasu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o response você envia respostas, como os dados de um formulário html, os dados são enviados na response.